# Opening secondary window in Java FX as child, forces overlap - anyway to overcome it?

Tags: javafx-8

I am attempting a simple app in Java FX 8 where I will have a window which is the main application and presents a list of to-do's.

When you select a to-do it opens a child window related to the to-do that was opened.

However, the child window will always be in front of the parent (unless side by side), but I will allow opening multiple windows, and navigation back to the parent.

Is there a way to allow the parent to become fully in view while still having the secondary window as a child?

Sample code:

```
Scene secondScene = new Scene(root, 800, 400);
    Stage secondStage = new Stage();
    secondStage.setTitle("Your to-do.....");
    secondStage.setScene(secondScene);
    secondStage.initStyle(StageStyle.DECORATED);
    secondStage.initModality(Modality.NONE);
    secondStage.initOwner(primaryStage);
    primaryStage.toFront();
    secondStage.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you already try `secondStage.setAlwaysOnTop(false)`? I'd assume it's `true` by default, that's why the behaviour.

Answer (score -1):

You could use:

```
secondStage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
```

You can find a reference here: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/stage/Modality.html